# Motion Tween Doesn't Work Inside Function in ActionScript 3 and Flash CS5

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

i have a problem with putting a motion tween in function. my code works perfectly in CS4(but unfortunatly flash CS4 hangs all the time on my PC. whoever in CS5 the motion works fine outside function but when i put it inside a function it behave strangely? i must mention that i'm not a pro in flash and sorry for my poor english.

i have a rectangle shape converted to symbol that i named it s1
here is the code without function:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.motion.AnimatorFactory;
import fl.motion.MotionBase;
import flash.filters.*;
import flash.geom.Point;
import fl.motion.Motion;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

var __motion_UIL1:MotionBase;
if(__motion_UIL1 == null) 
{
    import fl.motion.Motion;
    __motion_UIL1 = new Motion();
    __motion_UIL1.duration = 15;
    //__motion_UIL1.overrideTargetTransform();

    __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("x", [-280,-260,-240,-220,-200,-180,-160,-140,-120,-100,-80,-60,-40,-20,0]);
    __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("y", [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);

    __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("scaleX", [1.000000]);
    __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("scaleY", [1.000000]);
    __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("skewX", [0]);
    __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("skewY", [0]);
    __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("rotationConcat", [0]);
    __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("blendMode", ["normal"]);
    __motion_UIL1.initFilters(["flash.filters.BlurFilter"], [0], -1, -1);

    __motion_UIL1.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "blurX", [200,185.714,171.429,157.143,142.857,128.571,114.286,100,85.7143,71.4286,57.1429,42.8572,28.5715,14.2857,0], -1, -1);
    __motion_UIL1.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "blurY", [0], -1, -1);  

    __motion_UIL1.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "quality", [BitmapFilterQuality.LOW], -1, -1);

    var __animFactory_UIL1:AnimatorFactory = new AnimatorFactory(__motion_UIL1);
    __animFactory_UIL1.transformationPoint = new Point(0.500000, 0.500000);

    __animFactory_UIL1.addTarget(s1, 1);
}
```

and here when i put motion tween inside function:
(i have a rectangle shape converted to symbol that i named it s1)

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.motion.AnimatorFactory;
import fl.motion.MotionBase;
import flash.filters.*;
import flash.geom.Point;
import fl.motion.Motion;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

function b1(UILx:DisplayObject)
{
    var __motion_UIL1:MotionBase;
    if(__motion_UIL1 == null) 
    {
        import fl.motion.Motion;
        __motion_UIL1 = new Motion();
        __motion_UIL1.duration = 15;
        //__motion_UIL1.overrideTargetTransform();

        __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("x", [-280,-260,-240,-220,-200,-180,-160,-140,-120,-100,-80,-60,-40,-20,0]);
        __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("y", [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);

        __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("scaleX", [1.000000]);
        __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("scaleY", [1.000000]);
        __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("skewX", [0]);
        __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("skewY", [0]);
        __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("rotationConcat", [0]);
        __motion_UIL1.addPropertyArray("blendMode", ["normal"]);
        __motion_UIL1.initFilters(["flash.filters.BlurFilter"], [0], -1, -1);

        __motion_UIL1.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "blurX", [200,185.714,171.429,157.143,142.857,128.571,114.286,100,85.7143,71.4286,57.1429,42.8572,28.5715,14.2857,0], -1, -1);
        __motion_UIL1.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "blurY", [0], -1, -1);  

        __motion_UIL1.addFilterPropertyArray(0, "quality", [BitmapFilterQuality.LOW], -1, -1);

        var __animFactory_UIL1:AnimatorFactory = new AnimatorFactory(__motion_UIL1);
        __animFactory_UIL1.transformationPoint = new Point(0.500000, 0.500000);

        __animFactory_UIL1.addTarget(UILx, 1);
    }
}

b1(s1);
```

and now this is work with CS4 and it isn't work in CS5.
pleeeeeeease help me

Comment: Aside from the code looking like a minor trainwreck this seems to compile and works just fine as a timeline script. Can you be more specific with the problem? Are you getting errors?

Comment: no. no error at all. but first code blur and move my s1 symbol on screen in 15 frame and second code do the blur without move in 1 frame (no animation for blur or move).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__motion_UIL1 and __animFactory_UIL1 are both declared as local variables (inside the function), which essentally means they are erased and forgotten after the function is executed.  Try moving

```
var __motion_UIL1:MotionBase;
```

and

```
var __animFactory_UIL1:AnimatorFactory;
```

out of the function body.

Comment: Plus, I agree with @grapefrukt: The code *does* look like a minor trainwreck ;)

Comment: thanks. that was very helpful. i test your suggestion and you were right. but in flash cs4 i don't have this problem. and if i use your way then i won't able to use this function dynamically with any other movie clip or display object in run time? do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It shouldn't have worked in CS4 either ;)  The fact that id did might be related to a different garbage collection mechanism, but it was really just a coincidence at best.  You can still use the function dynamically, but you'll have to either build a class around it (and instantiate it with "new" for each of the display objects you want to move) or use one MotionBase and one AnimatorFactory for each motion, passing both as parameters to the function along with the display object.

Comment: thank you very much. second way you mentioned would be easier for me. you were very helpful. thanks again